# Why Angular says that cross origin request occurs when there's actually no any?

Tags: angularjs, express

I am trying to serve Angular application using ExpressJS. Here is my index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'fake_data')));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/pages');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

In my angular app there is also a constant containing API server address:

```
(function () {
   angular.module('Bankbox')
       .constant('webConfig', {
           API_SERVER: ''
       });
})();
```

It is been set during run phase:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('Bankbox')
        .config(bankboxConfig)
        .run(runConfig);


    function runConfig($location, webConfig){
        var port = ":" + $location.port() + "/";

        webConfig.API_SERVER = $location.host();

        if (port){
            webConfig.API_SERVER += port;
        }
    }
    .....
```

Finally when i execute `node index.js`, and trying to load 'localhost:8000' in the browser i get an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/fake_data/my-deals.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

The GET request is in a factory and it looks like:

```
function getMyDeals() {
            return $http.get(webConfig.API_SERVER + 'fake_data/my-deals.json')
                .then($http.getDataFromResult);
        }
```

Why this happens? I assumed that localhost:8000 shouldn't think of itself as an another origin.

Comment: are you sure you are opening page on `http://` protocol?